# Export csv file from collab notebook to google drive

Tags: python, pandas, csv, google-colaboratory

I am migrating from Visual Code to Google Colab however all my attempts to write a CSV file in the Goggle Drive have not been successful. I read some topics here on similar queries, however, I was not able to mount the code correctly - as I am getting this silliest error.

Code ran on Visual Code:

```
import facebook_scraper
import pandas as pd
import csv
from facebook_scraper import get_posts

listaBibliotecas = ["bibliotecafoa"]

for biblioteca in listaBibliotecas:
  print("Biblioteca: " + biblioteca) 
  all_posts = []
  try:
    all_posts = get_posts(biblioteca, pages=300)
  except Exception:
    print(f"Error while requesting Biblioteca: {biblioteca}")
    print("Checking the next one..")
  for post in all_posts:
    post['title'] = biblioteca
    print(post['title'])    
    print(post['post_id'])
    print(post['time'])
    print(post['text'])
    print(post['image'])
    print(post['video'])
    print(post['likes'])
    print(post['comments'])
    print(post['shares'])
    print(post['link'])
     
    data = [post['title'],post['post_id'], post['time'], post['text'], post['image'], post['video'], post['likes'], post['comments'], post['shares'], post['link']]

    with open("funcionaporfavor.csv", "a", newline="", encoding="utf-8") as f:
      writer = csv.writer(f)
      writer.writerow(data)
```

**Mounting the Drive**

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount ('/drive')
```

**New Code with df**

```
import facebook_scraper
import pandas as pd
import csv
from facebook_scraper import get_posts

listaBibliotecas = ["bibliotecafoa"]

for biblioteca in listaBibliotecas:
  print("Biblioteca: " + biblioteca) 
  all_posts = []
  try:
    all_posts = get_posts(biblioteca, pages=300)
  except Exception:
    print(f"Error while requesting Biblioteca: {biblioteca}")
    print("Checking the next one..")
  for post in all_posts:
    post['title'] = biblioteca
    print(post['title'])    
    print(post['post_id'])
    print(post['time'])
    print(post['text'])
    print(post['image'])
    print(post['video'])
    print(post['likes'])
    print(post['comments'])
    print(post['shares'])
    print(post['link'])
     
    data = [post['title'],post['post_id'], post['time'], post['text'], post['image'], post['video'], post['likes'], post['comments'], post['shares'], post['link']]
    
    df_fdist.to_csv('/content/drive/My Drive/data.csv')
```

**Error**

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-09d5240acb25> in <module>()
     29     data = [post['title'],post['post_id'], post['time'], post['text'], post['image'], post['video'], post['likes'], post['comments'], post['shares'], post['link']]
     30 
---> 31     df_fdist.to_csv('/content/drive/My Drive/data.csv')

NameError: name 'df_fdist' is not defined
```

**Expected outcome**

I need to fix this code in order to have the results written on my Google Drive.

Comment: `df_fdist` is not initialized and assigned anywhere in your code. Probably you wanted to `data.to_csv('/content/drive/My Drive/data.csv')`

Comment: hey @AshuGrover I see that, but I am not sure how to fix it. I am a N00b here :(

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
df_fdist.to_csv('/content/drive/My Drive/data.csv')
```

Use:

```
data.to_csv('/content/drive/My Drive/data.csv')
```